# Change column count in different views

Tags: css, flexbox, bulma

Two columns in mobile view and three columns in desktop view.

**Example**

```css
* {
  border: 1px solid;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.flexbox {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.flexbox>div {
  width: 33.333%;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 768px) {
  .flexbox>div {
    width: 50%;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="flexbox">
  <div>DIV 1</div>
  <div>DIV 2</div>
  <div>DIV 3</div>
  <div>DIV 4</div>
  <div>DIV 5</div>
  <div>DIV 6</div>
</div>
```

I was wondering, how you would do this with bulma.

**Attempt**

```
<div class="columns is-mobile is-multiline">
  <div class="column is-4-desktop is-6-mobile">DIV 1</div>
  <div class="column is-4-desktop is-6-mobile">DIV 2</div>
  <div class="column is-4-desktop is-6-mobile">DIV 3</div>
  <div class="column is-4-desktop is-6-mobile">DIV 4</div>
  <div class="column is-4-desktop is-6-mobile">DIV 5</div>
  <div class="column is-4-desktop is-6-mobile">DIV 6</div>
</div>
```

In mobile view it is correct, but not in desktop view.

What is missing?

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ttu4wm6t/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You must define tablet size as well to fit your desktop size since the size in between desktop and mobile is tablet for bulma.

```
 <div class="columns is-mobile is-multiline">
      <div class="column is-4-desktop is-4-tablet is-6-mobile">DIV 1</div>
      <div class="column is-4-desktop is-4-tablet is-6-mobile">DIV 2</div>
      <div class="column is-4-desktop is-4-tablet is-6-mobile">DIV 3</div>
      <div class="column is-4-desktop is-4-tablet is-6-mobile">DIV 4</div>
      <div class="column is-4-desktop is-4-tablet is-6-mobile">DIV 5</div>
      <div class="column is-4-desktop is-4-tablet is-6-mobile">DIV 6</div>
    </div>
```